# Unable to Generate Client token using Braintree API through .net

Tags: .net, braintree

Unable to generate the client token using my client side Javascript code. However i was able to communicate to the Braintree servers and able to create transactions at their end. But my return Result is empty/null. Can i have some Braintree developer assisting me on this.?

```
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //Gateway
        //This is the Braintree Gateway that we will use to post the transaction
        //to.  This is included here in the example but should be extracted out
        //into some static class somewhere.  Possibly in another layer.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        BraintreeGateway Gateway = new BraintreeGateway
        {
            Environment = Braintree.Environment.SANDBOX,
            PublicKey = "MY PUBLIC KEY",
            PrivateKey = "MY PRIVATE KEY",
            MerchantId = "MY MERCHANT ID"
        };

        string tokenID = Gateway.ClientToken.generate();

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //Transaction Request
        //This is the actual transaction request that we are posting to the 
        //Braintree gateway.  The values for number, cvv, month and year have 
        //been encrypted above using the braintree.js.  If you were to put a 
        //watch on the actual server controls their ".Text" property is blank
        //at this point in the process.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        TransactionRequest transactionRequest = new TransactionRequest
        {
            Amount = 100.00M,
            //PaymentMethodNonce = 
            CreditCard = new TransactionCreditCardRequest
            {
                Number = number,
                CVV = cvv,
                ExpirationMonth = month,
                ExpirationYear = year                    
            }                

        };

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //Transaction Result
        //Here we are going to post our information, including the encrypted
        //values to Braintree.  
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------            
        Result<Transaction> result = Gateway.Transaction.Sale(transactionRequest);
```

Here result returning me null transaction value but my transactions are being created at Braintree end. In my sandbox account i could see bunch of my transactions created,AUTHORIZED there. Im unable to get the exact transaction ID and the entire transaction attribute is returning me NULL.. Am i missing some thing?

Comment: Hi, I work at Braintree. The client token you generated on your server is what should be used by your client side code, could you share your Javascript so we could see how you are setting up Braintree on the client?

Comment: Yeah understood that point and i was able to do it successfully. Thank you cdeist

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it.